# Trying to create an API but Java Spring Boot can not read postgresql table column's name with sign double quotes on it. Error SQLState: 42703

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, api

I was trying to create an API but Java Spring Boot can not read postgresql table column's name with sign double quotes on it. It throws error 'SQLState: 42703' and 'ERROR: Column a1_0.xx does not exist'. In Postman it threw '500 Internal Server Error'

So, the case is I was trying to create an API with Java Spring Boot.

I have two tables. Both was created with postgresql. Both also has a structure like this:

```
------------+-------------------+----------+
alId        | alName            | alPoints |
[PK] bigint | character varying | bigint   |
------------+-------------------+----------+
101         | Name 1            | 70       |
102         | Name 2            | 80       |
103         | Name 3            | 90       |
------------+-------------------+----------+
```

First table's name is 'alien_rest'.  Second table's name is 'alien_rest3'. I created the second one to check what is wrong with first one.

Because whenever I try to execute 'select * from public.alien_rest' for first table through method '.findAll()', it threw errors like below. What confuse me, somehow everything works fine when I execute 'select * from public.alien_rest3' for second table.

While in Postman, it threw error message '500 Internal Server Error'

```
2023-05-23T12:02:31.301+07:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m7520[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
[2m2023-05-23T12:02:31.302+07:00[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m7520[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m ERROR: column a1_0.al_id does not exist
  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "a1_0.alId".
  Position: 8
[2m2023-05-23T12:02:31.323+07:00[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m7520[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select a1_0.al_id,a1_0.al_name,a1_0.al_points from alien_rest a1_0] [ERROR: column a1_0.al_id does not exist
  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "a1_0.alId".
  Position: 8] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause
```

I check through pgAdmin (mine is pgAdmin 4 version 7.1), turn out there is a difference with format of both column's name. 'alien_rest' use sign "" for its columns'name while alien_rest3 does not use sign "" for its columns'name.

For first table or 'alien_rest', it has format like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.alien_rest
(
    "alId" bigint NOT NULL,
    "alName" character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "alPoints" bigint,
    CONSTRAINT alien_rest_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("alId")
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

while for the second table or 'alien_rest3', is has format like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.alien_rest3
(
    alid bigint NOT NULL,
    alname character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    alpoints bigint,
    CONSTRAINT alien_rest3_pkey PRIMARY KEY (alid)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

I am not sure what I did that cause table 'alien_rest' use sign double quotes for its column's name.

It seems like the sign double quotes (or "") in the column's name is the one who give problem to the Spring Boot to read the first table or 'alien_rest'.

So, what is going on here? What can I do to fix the problem. Thank you for any help ;)

To make things clear, here is my codes in my Spring Boot project:

AlienResource.java

```
package com.kastamer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController //DEFINE that THIS CLASS is TECHNICALLY now A CONTROLLER FOR the APP 'SpringBootRest'
public class AlienResource {

    @Autowired
    AlienRepositoryDAO ard;
    
    @GetMapping("aliens")
    public List<Alien> getAliens() {
        
        List<Alien> aliens = (List<Alien>) ard.findAll();
        return aliens;
    }
}
```

Alien.java

```
package com.kastamer;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityResult;
import jakarta.persistence.FieldResult;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "alien_rest")//, schema = "public") //THIS is NOT WORKING with/without 'schema' for TABLE alien_rest
/* --> THIS is NOT WORKING for TABLE alien_rest
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "AlienMapping", entities = @EntityResult(entityClass = Alien.class, 
        fields = {
                @FieldResult(name = "alId", column = "alId"),
                @FieldResult(name = "alName", column = "alName"),
                @FieldResult(name = "alPoints", column = "alPoints")
        })) */
public class Alien {

    @Id
    //Column(name = "\"alId\"") --> PUT SIGN '\"' to VALUE does NOT HELP ANY
    @Column(name = "alId") //THIS is NOT WORKING for TABLE alien_rest
    private int alId;
    //Column(name "\"alName\"") --> PUT SIGN '\"' to VALUE does NOT HELP ANY
    @Column(name = "alName") //THIS is NOT WORKING for TABLE alien_rest
    private String alName;
    //Column(name "\"alPoints\"") --> PUT SIGN '\"' to VALUE does NOT HELP ANY
    @Column(name = "alPoints") //THIS is NOT WORKING for TABLE alien_rest
    private int alPoints;
    
    public int getAlId() {
        return alId;
    }
    public void setAlId(int alId) {
        this.alId = alId;
    }
    public String getAlName() {
        return alName;
    }
    public void setAlName(String alName) {
        this.alName = alName;
    }
    public int getAlPoints() {
        return alPoints;
    }
    public void setAlPoints(int alPoints) {
        this.alPoints = alPoints;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Alien [alName=" + alName + ", alPoints=" + alPoints + ", alId=" + alId + "]";
    }   
}
```

AlienRepositoryDAO.java

```
package com.kastamer;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface AlienRepositoryDAO extends CrudRepository<Alien, Integer>{

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.kastamer</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootRest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBootRest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You need to include the quote in the column name something like `name="'\"alId\"'"` as you probably need to quote the name as well. Or `name="\"alId\"` and add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true` to the `application.properties`.

Comment: I have tried to write name="\"alId\"" before but it didn't work. I also already try to put back  'name' again together with the property you suggest to application.properties but still doesn't make any difference.

Comment: You should use `"\"alId\""` with the property else include it in backticks (not single quotes) in the name (cannot do that here because that will quote it in the comments.

Comment: Ya, i have tried all of these `name="\"alId\""` for `alID`, `name="\"alName\""` for `alName`, and `name="\"alPoints\""` for `alPoints`. I even use your suggestion to use this `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true` in `application.properties` but still does not work.  Is there anything that I miss?

Comment: Try including backticks `\`` in the column names next to the quotes.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. Adding the quotes and quoting it as an identifier should make it work.

Comment: Done that. Get this error instead `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Identifier text should not contain quote markers (` or ")`

Comment: well, thanks anyway